# launching GUI for WSL from batch script

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
edit 

- my specs:
win 10  (10.0.18362 Build 18362)
Ubuntu LTS (18.04)


- Topic Enivornment Variable:
Maybe i have named this sub topic wrong...
necessarry settings:
in ~/.bashrc add: 
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

When you use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) you can run commands from a batch file from the windows host system via:

```
wsl 'example command'
```

If you now want to launch any sort of graphical interface like xfce this would be with (executed in wsl-shell):

```
startxfce4
```

or

```
xfce4-session
```

but if you know want to make a launch batch file (x11-server is running!) :

```
wsl startxfce4
```

there is the following problem:

```
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux DESKTOP-6FQD834 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Mon Mar 18 12:02:00 PST 2019 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/kernel init=/init
Build Date: 03 June 2019  08:10:35AM
xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Oct 14 06:47:57 2019
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Input/output error)
(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I guess the error originates from the fact that you had to set an environment variable in wsl: at which monitor(x11-server) the graphical output should be directed...
My guess is: that wsl trys to launch xfce4 before the subsystem is fully initialized (=all environment variables are loaded, etc)

so i tryed some thing like:

```
wsl
sleep 10
wsl startxfce4
```

but this acts like there is only the first line of code...

*If I execute all steps separately all works fine...*

Comment: An environmental variable can have various scopes. If you know what variable it is why not check whenever it is set in the batch environment and if it is not just set it?